# Inventor flies around the world in a machine using beamed power

Tags: story-identification, books

I’m trying to track down a book I read around 50 years ago. Can’t remember author or title. Probably early 50’s vintage. Storyline was a wealthy inventor who flies a large flying machine around the world. Powered by an energy beam from a base station in England. Machine has reception horn on its roof which at one point gets semi-blocked with debris. Not a great book but one of my first sci-fi reads.

Comment: Any chance this could be a somewhat distorted recollection of Hugo Gernsbeck's "Ralph 124C 41+" from 1925? I was reminded of it when reading your question, though the details don't match very well.

Comment: No I don’t think it’s that one. It was around 1965 when I read it and it was a secondhand hardback. I had the impression it was probably very early 50s.

Comment: You might check into it. There were reprints from the 1950s per ISFDB.

Comment: I read the plot summary on Wikipedia. It’s definitely not that.